# SQL Server:An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling

I apologize I'm asking this question when this specific error type has already been asked multiple times before, but I've looked through them and am not explicitly seeing my answer.

I am trying to build a trigger that takes records inserted into a table (FDC_Trip_History), selects some information from the record, joins on other tables to pull additional data, etc. and inserts a record into another table (Staging).

I'm getting this error at the bottom of my script, the 4th line from the end after the FROM section.   Any idea why?

```
CREATE TRIGGER Insert_Trip_History ON FDC_Trip_History
AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --If inserted record reaches a certain 'status' of archive then continue
    If EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE inserted.description like '%archive%')

    BEGIN
        --If inserted record can be 'billed', and hasn't already been processed, then continue.
        IF EXISTS (    SELECT * FROM inserted 
                    INNER JOIN FDC_Trips on inserted.tdate = FDC_Trips.tdate and inserted.job = FDC_Trips.job and inserted.SourceDB = FDC_trips.sourceDB
                    INNER JOIN AMS.dbo.Billable_Outcome_Filter as eBill on FDC_trips.SourceDB = eBill.SourceDB and FDC_Trips.outcome = eBill.Outcome_Code)
        AND NOT EXISTS (     SELECT * FROM inserted
                            INNER JOIN Staging as Stg on inserted.tdate = Stg.tdate and inserted.job = Stg.job and inserted.sourcedb = Stg.sourceDB)
            BEGIN    
                INSERT INTO Staging
                    (EVENT_OPERATION,
                    EVENT_SOURCE_TABLE,
                    EVENT_PRIORITY,
                    EVENT_TIME_UPDATED,
                    EVENT_STATUS,
                    EVENT_COMMENT,
                    TDATE,
                    JOB,
                    SOURCEDB,
                    CUSTNO,
                    SHIFTNO,
                    TYPE,
                    PROFITCENTER,
                    BILLINGRATEPROFITCENTER)                
                SELECT 
                    'CREATE' as [EVENT_OPERATION],
                    'FDC_Trip_History' as [EVENT_SOURCE_TABLE],
                    '1' as [EVENT_PRIORITY],
                    GETDATE() as [EVENT_TIME_ADDED],
                    null as [EVENT_TIME_UPDATED],
                    '0' as [EVENT_STATUS],
                    ''  as [EVENT_COMMENT],
                    eTHistory.tdate as [TDATE],
                    eTHistory.job as [JOB],
                    eTHistory.sourcedb as [SOURCEDB],
                    eT.custno as [CUSTNO],
                    eT.shiftno as [SHIFTNO],
                    'Completed' as [TYPE],
                    --Decide Profit Center.  Profit center (PC) determined from dispatch zone (Trips.dzone)
                    CASE 
                        WHEN cType.descr LIKE 'ATS%'
                            THEN DispatchZone.ATS_ProfitCenter
                        ELSE DispatchZone.ProfitCenter
                    END,
                    --Decide Billing rate profit center.  Billing rate profit center (BRPC) determined from pickup zone.  Does ATS logic apply to BRPC too?
                    CASE
                        WHEN cType.descr LIKE 'ATS%'
                            THEN PickupZone.ATS_ProfitCenter
                        ELSE PickupZone.ProfitCenter
                    END
                     as [BILLINGRATEPROFITCENTER]
                    FROM inserted
                        INNER JOIN FDC_Trip_History as eTHistory
                        INNER JOIN FDC_Trips as eT on eTHistory.tdate = eT.tdate and eTHistory.job = eT.job and eTHistory.sourcedb = eT.sourcedb
                        LEFT JOIN Trips as T on T.tdate = eTHistory.tdate and T.sourcedb = eTHistory.sourceDB and T.Job = eTHistory.Job
                        LEFT JOIN Call_Types as cType on cType.code = eT.calltype and cType.sourceDB = eT.sourceDB
                        LEFT JOIN Zones as DispatchZone on DispatchZone.code = T.dzone
                        LEFT JOIN Zones as PickupZone on PickupZone.code = eT.puzone /* Error pops up right here */
            END
    END
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have forgotton the specify the join criteria for the `FDC_Trip_History` table (the first `INNER JOIN`).

In addition, you have 14 columns in your `INSERT` list but 15 in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Thanks Martin, someone pointed out the missing join criteria out the same time you posted. Added the extra column in the insert list too, thanks for the second set of eyes!